# How to fit a line in latex?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Let $G$ be a $3$-coloured digraph. A subgraph $\mathrm{H}$ of $G$ is called linear if each component of $\mathrm{H}$ is either an edge or a cycle. We call a component of a linear subgraph {\em nonsingular}, if it is a cycle having weight other than $1$. All other components, that is, a cycle of weight $1$ and an edge of any weight, are singular (Laplacian singular, see \cite{DS2}). We use $C_{\mathrm{H}}$ to denote the number of cycles in a linear subgraph $\mathrm{H}$. By $S_{\mathrm{H}}$ and $N_{\mathrm{H}}$, we denote the number of singular components and the number of nonsingular components in $\mathrm{H}$, respectively. By $\mathcal{C}_k$, we will denote the set $\{\mathrm{H}\mid\mathrm{H} \mbox{ is a linear subgraph of order } k \mbox{ of } G \mbox{ in which no cycle has weight } \pm\mathrm{i}\}$.

\end{document}
```

Here in the text, when I compile the last line goes outside the box. How to fit this line so that text does not go outside?

Comment: You should not use `\mbox`es like `\mbox{ in which no cycle has weight }`.

Comment: but if I remove it all the words get combined together (looks like '' isalinearsubgra pho f orderk'')

Comment: My guess would be to use `\text` instead

Comment: I had tried with that also. But still it remains the same

Comment: Could you show a picture of the problem, as I don't get any issues with your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\mbox` and `\text` will not text-wrap, use `$..$`s for math parts only.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Let $G$ be a $3$-coloured digraph. A subgraph $\mathrm{H}$ of $G$ is called linear if 
each component of $\mathrm{H}$ is either an edge or a cycle. We call a component of a 
linear subgraph {\em nonsingular}, if it is a cycle having weight other than $1$. All
other components, that is, a cycle of weight $1$ and an edge of any weight, are singular 
(Laplacian singular, see \cite{DS2}). We use $C_{\mathrm{H}}$ to denote the number of 
cycles in a linear subgraph $\mathrm{H}$. By $S_{\mathrm{H}}$ and $N_{\mathrm{H}}$, we 
denote the number of singular components and the number of nonsingular components in 
$\mathrm{H}$, respectively. By $\mathcal{C}_k$, we will denote the set 
\{$\mathrm{H}\mid\mathrm{H}$ is a linear subgraph of order $k$ of $G$ in which no 
cycle has weight $\pm\mathrm{i}$\}.

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: it is very nice...

Comment: Why `\{` and `\}` outside of math mode?

Comment: Better use `\( ... \)` to enclose inline math, it helps avoiding accidents (unclosed $ gets closed by an unrelated open $) and it easier to frob with regex tools.

Answer (score 4):

Just don't use such verbose set descriptions: your readers will have a hard time guessing where the set description starts and ends.

In the code below I added several ties `~`.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Let $G$ be a $3$-coloured digraph. A subgraph $\mathrm{H}$ of $G$ is called 
linear if each component of $\mathrm{H}$ is either an edge or a cycle. 
We call a component of a linear subgraph \emph{nonsingular}, if it is a cycle 
having weight other than~$1$. All other components, that is, a cycle of 
weight~$1$ and an edge of any weight, are singular (Laplacian singular, 
see~\cite{DS2}). We use $C_{\mathrm{H}}$ to denote the number of cycles in 
a linear subgraph~$\mathrm{H}$. By $S_{\mathrm{H}}$ and $N_{\mathrm{H}}$ 
we denote the number of singular components and the number of nonsingular 
components in~$\mathrm{H}$, respectively. By~$\mathcal{C}_k$ we will denote 
the set 
%%% $\{\mathrm{H}\mid\mathrm{H} \mbox{ is a linear subgraph of order } k 
%%%\mbox{ of } G \mbox{ in which no cycle has weight } \pm\mathrm{i}\}$.
of all linear subgraphs of~$G$ having order~$k$ and in which no cycle has 
weight~$\pm\mathrm{i}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note also `\emph{nonsingular}` rather than `{\em nonsingular}`. I'm not sure why the graph symbol is in italic, while the symbol for a subgraph is upright.

Do you need a comma after `By~$\mathcal{C}_k$`? Grammar would say no.

Comment: Much easier to read!

Comment: Just a nit to pick: when defining something, emphasize (like "... is called \emph{linear}...").

Comment: @vonbrand The OP used it for another term; whether using `\emph` for “linear” depends on the text preceding the present paragraph, but you’re probably right.